# R message "Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Locations 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. don't exist. i There are only 1 column" MBCB packge

Tags: r, background, bioconductor

I am trying to do a background correction on my data sets that has only 3 columns, when submitting my code I get the error "Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Locations 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. don't exist. i There are only 1 column". Actually my data has only 3 columns so I dont get the error.

This is the code:

```
MBCB::mbcb.main(GSE150738_Dataraw,GSE150738_Dataraw_ctrol,
    npBool=TRUE,
    rmaBool=FALSE,
    mleBool=FALSE,
    bayesBool=FALSE,
    gmleBool=FALSE,                      
    paramEstFile="/Users/juanitadussan/Dropbox/ESTUDIO/BIOMEDICA/TESIS/TESIS 1/Análisis de datos GSE/Datasets/Background correction_parameters.xlsx",
    bgCorrectedFile="/Users/juanitadussan/Dropbox/ESTUDIO/BIOMEDICA/TESIS/TESIS 1/Análisis de datos GSE/Datasets/Background correction_corrected.xlsx",
    iter=500,
    burn=200,
    normMethod="none",
    isRawBead=FALSE)
```

> Error in `stop_subscript()`:
> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Locations 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. don't exist.
> i There are only 1 column.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

A subset of the data is here:

Data 1:

```
dput(mydatasubset1)
structure(list(ID_REF = c("TC0100006437.hg.1", "TC0100006476.hg.1", 
"TC0100006479.hg.1", "TC0100006480.hg.1", "TC0100006483.hg.1"
), GSM4557962 = c("44.944035", "100.85072", "157.17555","89.425964", "68.77652"), GSM4557965 = c("42.962048", "126.33466", "139.22046", "139.04102", "79.80324")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Control:

```
dput(mydatasubset2)
structure(list(ID_REF = c("TC0100006437.hg.1", "TC0100006476.hg.1", 
"TC0100006479.hg.1", "TC0100006480.hg.1", "TC0100006483.hg.1"
), GSM4557961 = c("46.799675", "127.531555", "212.54181","121.27715", "70.95126"), GSM4557964 = c("49.06907", "147.042", "206.33817", "126.067024", "60.933674")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset by providing the `dput` or subset of your data. Here is a guide for doing so: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Hi! I have two data sets, my data for analysis and the control one I just added a subset of both into the question field. i am trying to do a background correction for these two files but I keep getting the column error.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. After grouping the original database by airline, I could not sort the result by total count of airlines.
The solution for me was very simple

The problematic code is below:

```
top_5_airLines <- (grouped[order(grouped$Total, decreasing = TRUE)]
```

The right code can be found here:

```
top_5_airLines <- (grouped[order(grouped$Total, decreasing = TRUE),])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the numbers numeric fields and make the ids row names. Currently, these datasets are `tibble`s. You'll have to change them to data frames first. Since you're not using normalization, you could use `mbcb.correct`, as well.

This is how I prepared the data.

```
library(MBCB)

mydatasubset1 <- structure(list(
  ID_REF = c("TC0100006437.hg.1", "TC0100006476.hg.1",
             "TC0100006479.hg.1", "TC0100006480.hg.1", "TC0100006483.hg.1"),
  GSM4557962 = c("44.944035", "100.85072", "157.17555", "89.425964", "68.77652"), 
  GSM4557965 = c("42.962048", "126.33466","139.22046", "139.04102", "79.80324")),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame"))

mydatasubset2 <- structure(list(
  ID_REF = c("TC0100006437.hg.1", "TC0100006476.hg.1","TC0100006479.hg.1", 
             "TC0100006480.hg.1", "TC0100006483.hg.1"),
  GSM4557961 = c("46.799675", "127.531555", "212.54181","121.27715", "70.95126"),
  GSM4557964 = c("49.06907", "147.042", "206.33817", "126.067024", "60.933674")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mydatasubset1$GSM4557962 <- as.numeric(mydatasubset1$GSM4557962)
mydatasubset1$GSM4557965 <- as.numeric(mydatasubset1$GSM4557965)
mydatasubset2$GSM4557961 <- as.numeric(mydatasubset2$GSM4557961)
mydatasubset2$GSM4557964 <- as.numeric(mydatasubset2$GSM4557964)

str(mydatasubset1)
str(mydatasubset2)

md1 <- as.data.frame(mydatasubset1)
md2 <- as.data.frame(mydatasubset2)

row.names(md1) <- md1$ID_REF
row.names(md2) <- md2$ID_REF

(md1 <- md1[, 2:3])
(md2 <- md2[, 2:3])
```

I used temp files for the output.

```
t1 <- tempfile()
t2 <- tempfile()

MBCB::mbcb.main(md1,
                md2,
                npBool = TRUE,
                rmaBool = FALSE,
                mleBool = FALSE,
                bayesBool = FALSE,
                gmleBool = FALSE,                      
                paramEstFile = t1, 
                bgCorrectedFile = t2, 
                iter = 500,
                burn = 200,
                normMethod = "none",
                isRawBead = FALSE)
# 1 / 2  complete.
# 2 / 2  complete.
```

This is the setup for `mbcb.correct`.

```
tellMe <- mbcb.correct(md1,
                       md2,
                       npBool = TRUE,
                       rmaBool = FALSE,
                       mleBool = FALSE,
                       bayesBool = FALSE,
                       gmleBool = FALSE,                      
                       # paramEstFile = t1, 
                       # bgCorrectedFile = t2, 
                       iter = 500,
                       burn = 200,
                       # normMethod = "none",
                       isRawBead = FALSE)
# 1 / 2  complete.
# 2 / 2  complete.
```

Comment: thanks!! I did what you said however i keep getting the following: Error in obsbead - mu.est : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(obsnc) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(obsnc) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(obsbead) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA. Do you know what this means?

Comment: Did you make the numbers numeric? In the data object in your question, all of your numbers were character fields. I changed them to numbers in my answer. Let me know if that doesn't work or if you're unsure where to go from here.

Comment: I was miss placing a [], it is working now! Thank you so much!